# Weird PySide2 QPushButton background colour when checked

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I can use a stylesheet to set the background colour of a QPushButton when it is clicked or checked. The checked colours are however not as I've set them; they include some raster pattern.

The code I use is:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton,
)
from PySide2.QtCore import (
    QSize,
)


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(180, 110))
        self.setWindowTitle('QPushButton Example')

        button0 = QPushButton('Button 0', self)
        button0.setCheckable(True)
        button0.setStyleSheet(
            """QPushButton { background-color: lightgrey; }"""
            """QPushButton::checked { background-color: blue; }"""
            """QPushButton::pressed { background-color: blue; }"""
        )
        button0.resize(100, 32)
        button0.move(50, 10)

        button1 = QPushButton('Button 1', self)
        button1.setCheckable(True)
        button1.setStyleSheet(
            """QPushButton { background-color: lightgrey; }"""
            """QPushButton::checked { background-color: red; }"""
            """QPushButton::pressed { background-color: red; }"""
        )
        button1.resize(100, 32)
        button1.move(50, 60)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As long as the buttons are clicked with the mouse, I get the correct colour:

[image: clicked colour]

When I push the button (when I 'check' the button), then I get the weird colours:

[image: checked colour]

How can I get the actual colour that I've set for 'checked' instead of this raster pattern?

Comment: Try to do `app.setStyle('fusion')` and report if it changes anything.

Comment: @musicamante If I use the 'fusion' style, the button behaves as I expect I would. I get a solid colour and not the raster pattern when the button is checked. This makes sense in the light of what @ Mohamad Raad wrote that, by default, QT uses or mimics the platform-specific style of the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will Work:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton,
)
from PySide2.QtCore import (
    QSize,
)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(180, 110))
        self.setWindowTitle('QPushButton Example')

        button0 = QPushButton('Button 0', self)
        button0.setCheckable(True)
        button0.setStyleSheet(
            """QPushButton { background-color: lightgrey; }"""
            """QPushButton:checked { background-color: blue; border: none;}"""
            """QPushButton:pressed { background-color: lightblue; border: none;}"""
        )

        button0.resize(100, 32)
        button0.move(50, 10)

        button1 = QPushButton('Button 1', self)
        button1.setCheckable(True)
        button1.setStyleSheet(
            """QPushButton { background-color: lightgrey; }"""
            """QPushButton:checked { background-color: red; border: none; }"""
            """QPushButton:pressed { background-color: pink; border: none; }"""
        )
        button1.resize(100, 32)
        button1.move(50, 60)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why removing the border has an effect on the colour when checked?

Comment: @NZD that may depend on the style. Please answer to my comment to your original question.

Comment: @NZD Qt provides platform-specific style implementations that aim to make buttons and other UI elements look and behave in a way that is consistent with the user's platform (e.g., Windows, macOS, Linux).

For example:
**On Windows:** The default style might use a solid border with a 1-pixel width when the button is not pressed. When the button is pressed, it may  darken the border and the button appear pushed in.
Appearance of QPushButton borders can also be influenced by your application's overall Qt style, which can be set globally. You can change the style using QApplication.setStyle()